# ?__store=store_view_code and category widget link

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, widgets

I'm using a category widget to generate a link to a category. However, the store code is appended to the URL. How do I prevent this.

```
{{widget type="catalog/category_widget_link" anchor_text="Mobile" title="Mobile" template="catalog/category/widget/link/link_inline.phtml" id_path="category/368"}}
```

And the URL which Magento generates:

`http://www.domain.com/path/to/category.html?__store=store_view_code`

Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I didn't set Add store codes to Url in backend.
[image: Backend settings]

Comment: Are you aware of the backend setting which appends store codes to the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty annoying as it tends to invalidate FPC implementations. We 'solved' this by rewriting `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Widget_Link::getHref` and removing the following section:

```
if(strpos($this->_href, "___store") === false){
    $symbol = (strpos($this->_href, "?") === false) ? "?" : "&";
    $this->_href = $this->_href . $symbol . "___store=" . $store->getCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution that worked well too.

Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Widget/Link.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Widget/Link.php`

Search for (line 91 in Magento 1.7.x / line 100 in Magento 1.9.x)

> $this->_href = $this->_href . $symbol . "___store=" . $store->getCode();

And modify to

> $this->_href = $this->_href;

Upload and save your changes and you'll now not have your widget (dynamically) inserted links getting appended with ?___store=default.

Credit: [DesignHaven](https://www.designhaven.co.uk/2013/10/force-removal-of-store-code-default-from-urls-in-magento/)